# Unity - Text changes size when changing resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, resize, game-engine

So, I have a scene where I have some basic elements: a crosshair, a health bar, and a name (a text). I have the canvas set to "scale with screen size" so when I change from, say, 1080p to 4K or GHD, or to a lower resolution, the elements on the UI stay the same size.

The thing is, it only works for the crosshair and the health bar. If I try seeing the game in 4K, the name gets a lot bigger, and if I select a lower resolution it becomes progressively smaller.

Any ideas of what can I do to make the text stay the same size?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[The size of the UI at 4K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tg04.png)

[Size at 1080p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO89a.png)

[Size at 16:9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWFA.png)

Comment: Did you tried canvas scaler? https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

Comment: @mharti yep, I have a canvas scaler. That's why the healthbar and the crosshair keep their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice is to use Layout groups , problem on your screen is that some of your elements are set to stretch and some dont.

For exaple this articicle is good.
https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/prototyping-ui-in-unity-part-4-layout-components-9a9451998203

But if you google anything with "layout group Unity" you will find what you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Any ideas of what can I do to make the text stay the same size?That is my idea.

Comment: Nope, the text still can't keep the same size. Thanks a lot, anyways, seems like this info will be really useful when doing menus.